# pdo get number of rows

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get the number of rows using pdo and if the number is less than 1 echo not found else do the other stuff. The below code isn't displaying "not found" if there are no results matching the where clause.

```
$options = array(
'results_per_page'              => 200,
'url'                           => 'index.php?page=*VAR*',
'db_handle'                     => $dbh
);


$page = $_GET['page'];

$paginate = new pagination($page, 'SELECT * FROM pants where size ="medium" or size ="M"  ORDER BY id desc', $options);
$result = $paginate->resultset->fetchAll();
if($result > 0)
        {

foreach($result as $row)
{
echo $row['title'];}
 else {
  echo "not found";}
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without seeing your pagination class, your schema, or anything else that would be useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare an array with a number, mind you (yeah, even in PHP).

To test if you have something in your array, simple

```
if($result)
```

is enough.

Note that your problem has nothing to do with getting *number* of rows. Actually you need to know if you have *any* rows, not count them.

Comment: `if($result)` then what? It would be much helpful if you include the full code.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
if(!empty($result))
```

instead of

```
if($result > 0)
```